# How to show this limit of distributions?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve the following exercise regarding limits of distributions:

> Establish the following limit (on the distributional sense)
>   $$\lim_{t\to 0\pm}\ln (\tau + it) = \ln |\tau| + i\pi H(-\tau),$$
>   where we are taking the principal branch of the log function, that is, $\arg(\tau+it)<\pi$ and $H(\tau)$ is the Heavside distribution. Relate this expression to the Plemelj-Sochozki's formula.

Now, since we want to compute the limit in the distributional sense, what we need to show is that if $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ then

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln(\tau + it)\phi(\tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln |\tau|\phi(\tau)d\tau + i\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(-\tau)\phi(\tau)d\tau.$$

To do this, I did the following: first we write down $\ln$ explicitly:

$$\ln(\tau+it)=\ln(\tau^2+t^2)^{1/2}+i\arg(\tau+it),$$

in that case we have:

$$(\ln(\tau+it),\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln(\tau^2+t^2)^{1/2}\phi(\tau)d\tau+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\arg(\tau+it)\phi(\tau)d\tau.$$

Let's call the first integral $I_1(t)$ and the second integral $I_2(t)$. On the second integral we see that we can rewrite it in the following way:

$$I_2(t)=\int_{-\infty}^0\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\dfrac{t}{\tau}\right)\phi(\tau)d\tau+\int_0^\infty \arctan\dfrac{\tau}{t}\phi(\tau)d\tau.$$

We then see the following:

1. When taking $\lim_{t\to 0}I_1(t)$, if we move the limit inside the integral we get $\lim_{t\to 0}\ln(\tau^2+t^2)^{1/2}=\ln |\tau|$. So that if we move the limit inside the integral we have $\lim_{t\to 0}I_1(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln|\tau| \phi(\tau)d\tau$.
2. When taking $\lim_{t\to 0}I_2(t)$, if we again move the limit inside the integrals, we get that $\lim_{t\to 0}I_2(t)=\pi\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(\tau)d\tau$.

In that case we get the result we wanted:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}(\ln(\tau+it),\phi)=(\ln|\tau|,\phi)+(i\pi H(-\tau),\phi),$$

but it all relies on moving the limit inside the integrals. This can really be done in this case? Isn't anything wrong here?

Comment: Something is not right here: your very last formula becomes problematic if $\tau = 0$ and $0 \in \text{supp} \phi$. In fact, the whole problem is meaningless for $\tau = 0$.

Comment: In truth I didn't notice at first the problem at $\tau = 0$. It was not a typo, though, since the limit is written exactly like that in the problem I'm trying to solve. Concering $H$ it is the Heavside distribution, so that it is given by $\phi \mapsto \int_0^\infty \phi$. I've added an edit regarding that.

Comment: There is a mistake in your argument: remember that $\arctan$ takes values only in $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$, while the argument of $\tau + \textrm i t$ should be in $(-\pi, \pi)$, therefore the term containing $\arctan$ is not right.

Comment: Let me reformulate my first remark: in the right-hand side of the original question, the distribution $\phi \mapsto \textrm i \pi \int _{-\infty} ^0 \phi$ is perfectly well defined; alas, the term $\phi \mapsto \int _{-\infty} ^\infty \ln |\tau| \phi (\tau) \textrm d \tau$ may be divergent or even not make sense because of $\ln$ in $0$. Therefore, it seems that you want to speak of something like the "principal value" of this integral, but I cannot be sure, not knowing the context that you are working in. You'll have to add the details yourself in the post.

Comment: I understand the remark. Indeed I hadn't noticed it, but after you posted the comment I saw that really the fact that $\ln$ is not defined at $0$ may cause problems regarding the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln |\tau|\phi(\tau)d\tau$. This is one exercise about distributions. I posted the original statement, but it's almost the same I wrote. Also, in the text the notation $\operatorname{Pv}$ is being used for principal value as well as $\operatorname{Pf}$ is being used for pseudo-function, meaning integration against the finite part of the integral, so I think this isn't the case.

Comment: The (probably real version of the) [Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Version_for_the_real_line) mentioned in the original statement makes indeed use of a principal value. Its relationship with your problem seems to be that the S.-P. theorem looks like the "differentiated" version of your problem: $\frac 1 \tau$ instead of $\ln$, Dirac's $\delta$ instead of Heaviside's $H$. So, I guess that you really need a p.v. in the right-hand side, in the term containing the $\ln$.

Comment: In the last few days I searched a little more on this and I've found out that $\ln |x|$ is locally integrable because $x\ln x \to 0$ when $x\to 0^+$. I believe this would solve the problem with the $\ln$ wouldn't? Now, in the end I got the result by taking the limits inside the integrals. I'm a little unsure if this could be done. Is this right anyway?

Comment: I confess that I don't follow your argument: yes, since $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \color{red} x \ln |x| = 0$ it follows that $\color{red} x \ln |x|$ is continuous, hence locally-integrable; but how does it follow that $\ln |x|$ (without the preceding $\color{red} x$) is locally-integrable too?

Comment: I did the following (which might as well be totally wrong and if it is, please tell me where is my mistake): since we are concerned with the case when $0$ is in inside the integral over which we are integrating we pick $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\ln|x|dx$, since the function is even this is $2\int_0^\epsilon \ln x dx = 2[x\ln x - x]_0^\epsilon$. This will give $2\epsilon \ln \epsilon - \epsilon$ because $x\ln x \to 0$ when $x\to 0$. Indeed, even if we consider the limit $\epsilon \to$ we will also get zero by this reasoning.

Comment: I can agree with you that it can be proven that $\ln |x|$ is Riemann improperly-integrable around $0$ - but does it follow that it is also Lebesgue locally-integrable around $0$? I don't know what to say.

Comment: About being Lesbegue integrable I don't really know. I haven't studied much about Lesbegue integral yet. By the way, as far as I know, the integrals appearing in the question are Riemann improper integrals.